# How do I sort by leaves only in a TreeTableView?

Tags: java, sorting, javafx

I am using the TreeTableView class in JavaFX to implement a grouped stock ticker watch list.  When sorting, I would like to only have the stocks sorted (not the groups).  Currently when I click on the "Symbol" column (for example), it sorts the stocks in each group (as I would expect) but it also orders the groups.

In my case, I would like to have only the stocks sorted in each group and preserve the order of the groups in my watch list.

I have tried using the setSortMode() method, but it only supports the following modes:
ALL_DESCENDANTS
ONLY_FIRST_LEVEL

I took a look at the source code for the TreeItem class and it looks like sorting by leaves only is not currently supported (but may be in the future).

```
  private void runSort(ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> children, Comparator<TreeItem<T>> comparator, TreeSortMode sortMode) 
  {
    if (sortMode == ALL_DESCENDANTS) {
        doSort(children, comparator);
    } else if (sortMode == ONLY_FIRST_LEVEL) {
        // if we are here we presume that the current node is the root node
        // (but we can test to see if getParent() returns null to be sure).
        // We also know that ONLY_FIRST_LEVEL only applies to the children
        // of the root, so we return straight after we sort these children.
        if (getParent() == null) {
            doSort(children, comparator);
        }
//  } else if (sortMode == ONLY_LEAVES) {
//      if (isLeaf()) {
//                // sort the parent once
//      }
//  } else if (sortMode == ALL_BUT_LEAVES) {
    } else {
        // Unknown sort mode
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to workaround this limitation without having to wait for support to be added in a future update of JavaFX?

Answer (score 4):

Quite a late response, but perhaps you can still use the feedback. I found 2 approaches for what you want.

*Option 1:* You could set your own sort policy. Here I've set a simple policy that sorts only the children of nodes directly beneath the root. You'll have to implement a sorting approach for every column and for every combination of columns.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeSortMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortOnlySome extends Application {

    private final TreeTableColumn<Person, String> tableColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Person");
    private final TreeTableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Age");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        TreeTableView<Person> treeTable = new TreeTableView();
        borderPane.setCenter(treeTable);

        setupColumns(treeTable);

        TreeItem<Person> root = new TreeItem<>(new Person("Root"));

        // Add some data
        populate(root);

        // Set the data into the treetable
        treeTable.setRoot(root);
        root.setExpanded(true);
        root.getChildren().forEach(c -> c.setExpanded(true));


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dont sort categories");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void setupColumns(TreeTableView<Person> treeTable) {
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().displayName));
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().age).asObject());

        treeTable.getColumns().setAll(tableColumn, ageColumn);

        treeTable.setSortPolicy(new Callback<TreeTableView<Person>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(TreeTableView<Person> table) {
                TreeItem<Person> rootItem = table.getRoot();
                if (rootItem == null) return false;

                TreeSortMode sortMode = table.getSortMode();
                if (sortMode == null) return false;

                // Collecto the column comparators and merge them into 1
                List<Comparator<Person>> comparators = new ArrayList<Comparator<Person>>();
                table.getSortOrder().stream().forEachOrdered(ttc -> {
                    Comparator<Person> columnComparator = getComparatorForColumn(ttc);
                    comparators.add(columnComparator);
                });
                Comparator<Person> merged = mergeComparators(comparators);

                rootItem.getChildren().forEach(c -> {
                    c.getChildren().sort((o1, o2) -> merged.compare(o1.getValue(), o2.getValue()));
                    // TODO: Sort recursively down c.getChildren()
                });

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private Comparator<Person> getComparatorForColumn(TreeTableColumn<Person, ?> column) {
        int sign = column.getSortType() == TreeTableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING ? 1 : -1;
        if (column == tableColumn) {
            Comparator<Person> nameCompare = new Comparator<Person>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                    Comparator c = column.getComparator();
                    Object obj1 = o1.displayName;
                    Object obj2 = o2.displayName;
                    return sign * c.compare(obj1, obj2);
                }
            };
            return nameCompare;
        } else if (column == ageColumn) {
            return new Comparator<Person>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                    return sign * Integer.compare(o1.age, o2.age);
                }
            };
        } else {
            // TODO: Comparators for other columns
            return new Comparator<Person>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                    return sign * 0;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public static Comparator<Person> mergeComparators(final Collection<Comparator<Person>> multipleOptions) {
        return new Comparator<Person>() {
            public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                for (Comparator option : multipleOptions) {
                    int result = option.compare(o1, o2);
                    if (result != 0) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    private void populate(TreeItem<Person> root) {
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Person("Group A")));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Person("Category 2")));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Person("Collection C")));

        // Add some people
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            String name = "Person " + (i + 1);
            Person someone = new Person(name);
            someone.age = 16 + i * 3;
            TreeItem categoryNode = root.getChildren().get(i % 3);
            categoryNode.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(someone));
        }
    }

    public class Person {
        public String displayName;
        public int age;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.displayName = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Option 2:* Alternative approach... let's look inside at what the treetableview does. To compare elements, it creates a (new) TableColumnComparatorBase. At some point in the callstack, class TableColumnComparatorBase will get the values of the column and use them to a comparison:

```
@Override public int compare(S o1, S o2) {
    for (TableColumnBase<S,T> tc : columns) {
        if (! isSortable(tc)) continue;

        T value1 = tc.getCellData(o1);
        T value2 = tc.getCellData(o2);

        int result = doCompare(tc, value1, value2);

        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Class class TableColumnBase that checks how to compare them:

```
public static final Comparator DEFAULT_COMPARATOR = (obj1, obj2) -> {
    if (obj1 == null && obj2 == null) return 0;
    if (obj1 == null) return -1;
    if (obj2 == null) return 1;

    if (obj1 instanceof Comparable && (obj1.getClass() == obj2.getClass() || obj1.getClass().isAssignableFrom(obj2.getClass()))) {
        return (obj1 instanceof String) ? Collator.getInstance().compare(obj1, obj2) : ((Comparable)obj1).compareTo(obj2);
    }

    return Collator.getInstance().compare(obj1.toString(), obj2.toString());
};
```

I couldn't find a way to set the comparators per column. But what we can do, is make sure that the values in the cells implement Comparable and return 0 when they shouldn't move. Note that not the items of your TreeItem, but the items produced by your CellValueFactory should implement Comparable. This unfortunately also means we need to add custom CellFactories or toStrings. It's not pretty at all, but below you'll find a working example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.text.Collator;

public class SortOnlySome extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        TreeTableView<Person> treeTable = new TreeTableView();
        borderPane.setCenter(treeTable);

        setupColumns(treeTable);

        TreeItem<Person> root = new TreeItem<>(new Person("Root", false));

        // Add some data
        populate(root);

        // Set the data into the treetable
        treeTable.setRoot(root);
        root.setExpanded(true);
        root.getChildren().forEach(c -> c.setExpanded(true));


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dont sort categories");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void setupColumns(TreeTableView<Person> treeTable) {
        TreeTableColumn<Person, NameSortWrapper> treeColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Person");
        treeColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(new NameSortWrapper(param.getValue().getValue())));
        TreeTableColumn<Person, AgeSortWrapper> ageColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(new AgeSortWrapper(param.getValue().getValue())));
        treeTable.getColumns().setAll(treeColumn, ageColumn);
    }

    private void populate(TreeItem<Person> root) {
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Person("Group A", false)));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Person("Category 2", false)));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Person("Collection C", false)));

        // Add some people
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            String name = "Person " + (i + 1);
            Person someone = new Person(name, true);
            someone.age = 16 + i * 3;
            TreeItem categoryNode = root.getChildren().get(i % 3);
            categoryNode.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(someone));
        }
    }

    // The class to show in the treetable
    // Problem 1: The data class defines whether sorting is allowed
    // Problem 2: Category nodes in the tree will also be TreeItem<Person>
    public class Person {
        public String displayName;
        public int age;
        boolean allowSorting = true;

        public Person(String name, boolean allowSort) {
            this.allowSorting = allowSort;
            this.displayName = name;
        }
    }

    // A class that implements Comparable and determines whether sorting should be done
    // To be extended for each column
    public abstract class SortWrapper implements Comparable {
        public final Person theRealData;

        public SortWrapper(Person theData) {
            this.theRealData = theData;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            if (theRealData.allowSorting) {
                return this.customCompare(o);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        protected abstract int customCompare(Object o);

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString();
        }
    }

    // A sort helper for the Person's name
    public class NameSortWrapper extends SortWrapper {
        public NameSortWrapper(Person theData) {
            super(theData);
        }

        @Override
        protected int customCompare(Object o) {
            return Collator.getInstance().compare(theRealData.displayName, ((NameSortWrapper) o).theRealData.displayName);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (theRealData == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return theRealData.displayName;
            }
        }
    }

    // A sort helper for the Person's age
    public class AgeSortWrapper extends SortWrapper {
        public AgeSortWrapper(Person theData) {
            super(theData);
        }

        @Override
        protected int customCompare(Object o) {
            return Integer.compare(theRealData.age, ((AgeSortWrapper) o).theRealData.age);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // Note that null is returned when !allowSorting, this makes sure
            // that the rows do not show an age for the categories
            if (theRealData == null || !theRealData.allowSorting) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return Integer.toString(theRealData.age);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```